# How to set number of cards per row in card-deck in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I am looking for solution fot setting number of cards in card-deck per row in bootstrap.

For example, I would like to have two cards per row:

```html
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you wanted??

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="card col-sm-6">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-6">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-6">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-6">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! And there is a possibility to add gap between cards?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="card-deck row">
  <div class="card col-sm-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
    Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
          Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
          Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-sm-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
          Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I would like to have two cards per row"* - Did you miss that? It would be helpful if you **explained** the changes you made and why rather than just dumping code.

Comment: there you can add two cards in one row by using class col-sm-6

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want like this:
and you want more **gap between cards** you change the class **`.md-3` to `.md-4`**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="card my-3">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Card text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Card footer text</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @profiler this above example for i add gap between card.